# "Wildcard" and "or" in search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, wildcards

If I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-*%20or%20java) search (questions tagged .net-* or java), java is put in *and* to the last tag that starts with .net (at this time, on the right I get "or [.net-interview](/questions/tagged/.net-interview) or [.net-internalsor](/questions/tagged/.net-internalsor) [java](/questions/tagged/java)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed (probably when the search engine was changed). Now for the same search I get  "or [.net-services](/questions/tagged/.net-services) or [.net-4.0-rc1](/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-rc1) or [java](/questions/tagged/java)"